# SSRS web URL not accessible by windows domain

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS running and it's only accessible by the localhost. It's configured to work with the windows domain. The URL shows that it should be windows domain. Yet, when I go to the http://mywindowsdomain/Reports/  it prompts me with a user and password window and then fails on every user. When I do the same for http://localhost/Reports/ it automatically logs in for the user.

I tried to add the windows header name in the advanced configuration. It still failed. When I looked at a mirror of this SSRS installation on another machine, there is no difference in configuration. They are both the exact same installation, just using different domains and mirrored databases.

The SSRS log on the machine shows SSRS running both locally:80 and on the domain:80.

Why would it work locally but not with the domain? Firewall?

**Possible Leads**

This seems exactly what I'm dealing with. I will try this is report back.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukaszp/archive/2008/03/26/solving-the-reporting-services-login-issue-in-the-february-ctp-of-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It was the RSWindowsNegotiate authentication option enabled along with the RSWindowsNTLM in the config file. Removed the RSWindowsNegotiate and left just the RSWindowsNTLM, restarted the service and was able to access via windows header.

> 1) Remove RSWindowsNegotiate and ensure RSWindowsNTLM is specified in
>   the file rsreportserver.config